# How to make only one datagridview cell RightToLeft is false

Tags: c#, datagridview, right-to-left

I have datagridview and its RTL is True now when I entering float or negative numbers it make them opposite Like this example :

Entered number : .2 or -.2.

When `Datagridview_CellEndEdit` Numbers will be like this : 2. or 2.- .

Thank you.

Comment: Don't know RTL to be honest - but I would assume `2.` to be correct because you are reading it from right to left so the order would be 0 -> . -> 2 == 0.2 ?!?

Comment: @RandRandom thank you for your reply. Yes you are correct and its correct 2. its 0.2 but 0.2 good look and understandable for basic user than 2.    .

Comment: Maybe consider the cellformat to `"#,##0.00"` - https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: Here an example to see the difference between specifying 0 vs # - https://dotnetfiddle.net/daXsPi

Comment: It works, I don't know how to thank you very much sir.